# janusgraph doesn't allow me to set TTL with AWSKeyspace as the backend

Tags: janusgraph

I'm using janusgraph with AWSKeyspace (cassandra) and elasticsearch as the storage and indexing backends respectively.
I have a requirement to delete all the edges older than 30days. Setting a TTL on edge property doesn't work as expected(error below).

```
ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager  - Could not create GremlinScriptEngine for gremlin-groovy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The storage engine does not support TTL
```

My script is below:

```
edgeId = mgmt.getPropertyKey("edge_id")
sourceId = mgmt.getPropertyKey("source_id")
severity = mgmt.getPropertyKey("severity")
source = mgmt.getPropertyKey("source")
createdAt = mgmt.getPropertyKey("created_at")
alertStatus = mgmt.getPropertyKey("alert_status")
investigationStatus = mgmt.getPropertyKey("investigation_status")
investigationPriority = mgmt.getPropertyKey("investigation_priority")
attributes = mgmt.getPropertyKey("attributes")
edgeType = mgmt.getPropertyKey("edge_type")

if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex(edgeIndexName)) {
    mgmt.buildIndex(edgeIndexName, Edge.class).
            addKey(edgeType, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).
            addKey(tenant, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).
            addKey(severity, Mapping.DEFAULT.asParameter()).
            addKey(source, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).
            addKey(createdAt, Mapping.DEFAULT.asParameter()).
            addKey(investigationPriority, Mapping.DEFAULT.asParameter()).
            addKey(attributes, Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).
            buildMixedIndex(indexBackendName)
}
makeEdgeCompositeIndex(mgmt, edgeCompositeIndexName, edgeId)
makeEdgeCompositeIndex(mgmt, edgeCompositeIndexName, sourceId)
// ###########
// Add TTL
// ###########
mgmt.setTTL(sourceId, Duration.ofDays(30))
```

I did try replacing AWSKeyspace with cassandra and run the same script in a docker compose file and it works well(setting of TTL). Just like cassandra AWSKeyspace supports adding TTLs.

Answer (score 2):

When using Amazon Keyspaces, TTL needs to be enabled using a statement such as

```
ALTER TABLE my_table WITH CUSTOM_PROPERTIES={'ttl':{'status': 'enabled'}};
```

Comment: Tried it. It did not work. I think this is the PR where cell level TTL feature is set to false in case of AWSKeyspace   https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/2644

Answer (score 2):

See [https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/ba90c0eea2ed9df65fd72b3c56e5a1215a51[…]janusgraph/diskstorage/cql/builder/CQLStoreFeaturesBuilder.java](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/ba90c0eea2ed9df65fd72b3c56e5a1215a51%5B%E2%80%A6%5Djanusgraph/diskstorage/cql/builder/CQLStoreFeaturesBuilder.java)

This was set false likely because keyspaces TTL support went GA after the PR for keyspaces support was done:

PR: June 2021 https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/pull/2644

TTL GA: Oct 2021 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/announcing-amazon-keyspaces-time-to-live-ttl-general-availability/

This could be set to true now, if tested to work.

Comment: opened a bug for the same https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/3325

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed as of v1.0.0 https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc1

Comment: Just as a clarification: 1.0.0 wasn't released yet, this is a release candidate for 1.0.0. Thanks for the contribution by the way :)

Comment: Sorry for jumping the gun here